# Invoke React Functional Component’s function from Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, jsx, react-devtools

```
function App() {
 
 const someFn = () => { 
   console.log('hey!') 
  }

 
return <div>...</div> 

}
```

So once the website has loaded and the component has been mounted, is it possible to somehow access the javascript and invoke someFn()?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you attach it to the window object like so: `window.someFn = someFn`